# Is it necessary to save any binary files from InnoDB in addition to mysqldump?

Tags: innodb, mysql

I've just migrated a database from `MyISAM` engine to `InnoDB`. I use `mysqldump` to back up my `MyISAM` database, but when I took a look in the `MySQL` [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-backup.html), for InnoDB table I need also to save the binary files (along with `mysqldump`).

My question is, why these binary files are important and what they do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you're using `mysqldump`, it is producing a logical copy of your database. It is not necessary to save any of the (binary) data files. However, it is possible to take a binary backup *instead* of a `mysqldump` backup.